# Is there any way to run macros in background?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way by which VBA can be running in the background i.e. even when the workbook is not active but the machine is on?

Comment: The workbook needs to be open for macros to run.

Comment: Needs to be open, but need not be active, though.

Comment: You could schedule a Task (in windows) to open the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable screen updating and minimize the excel file to allow a macro to "run in the background" but the excel file must be open.